# Remove index.php - file on multlilingual Joomla Site

Tags: joomla-3.x, .htaccess-configuration

As supported by various posts, I did :

- change the htaccess.txt - file name to .htaccess via FTP
- set the URL - Rewrite Option in the Joomla Configuration Options to "YES"

Result:
- index.php is removed from all URLs
- all pages work, EXCEPT the start page of each language. The startpage of these pages is, for german, english and french:

www.mydomain.com/de/
www.mydomain.com/en/
www.mydomain.com/fr/

Result for these landing pages is a 404 Error. When I however remove the trailing slash of all of them, the landing pages can be found perfectly.

So what shall I do ? Remove the trailing slashes from ONLY the start pages (all other pages don't get any trailing slashes..); and if yes; how ?

Other ideas?

My .htacess-file content:

```
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (de|en|es|fr)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.

AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php .php5
```

Answer (score 0):

This should target the start page of each language, only when it has a trailing slash.  Then it will remove the trailing slash.  If you need something else, please comment and I will adjust it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (de|en|es|fr)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Not working bruh.. Exact same result as above :/

Comment: Btw, if this may interest you. On the FTP root there is a .htaccess file (the one I've renamed from htaccess.txt to .htaccess), a .htaccess.orig, as well as a 3htaccess_backup file. What are those?

Comment: Those other files are just backups.  Please put a full example url input (like https://www.mydomain.com/fr/) and expected output (like https://www.mydomain.com/fr) . I tested my code using https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ with those and it works

Comment: @ YellowWebMonkey well as I said the default homepage URL is mydomain.com/index.php/en/, but returns a 404, and I find it if it is mydomain.com/index.php/en (without trailing slash); whereas I still would like to have mydomain.com/en as the final result. Any idea?

Comment: So mydomain.com/index.php/en/ redirect to mydomain.com/en directly? or mydomain.com/index.php/en/ redirect to mydomain.com/index.php/en, but display mydomain.com/en (masked)? If first, my answer should do that https://share.getcloudapp.com/DOujDz9R.  If latter, what would you like other subpages to do?

Comment: I don't want anything to be redirected actually, I want the link mydomain.com/index.php/en/ to be mydomain.com/en instead.

Comment: I succeeded to take out the index.php from the URL, but the result is mydomain.com/en/ instead of mydomain.com/en
so how can I get rid of the trailing slash?